# Grouped custom design time properties in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, properties, design-time

I've seen similar questions asked before about this, but not precisely what I'm after.

I have a User Control and would like to build in an expandable bunch of properties for editing the control at design time.  Note, NOT a group of properties but a list of properties similar to the Size or Location properties which you can open up to reveal other properties.  Is this possible and how would I go about doing it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to "group" your properties into a class and then apply a TypeConverter:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]
public class MyProperties {
  public string Item1 { get; set; }
  public string Item2 { get; set; }
}
```

Then your UserControl would use that class instead of the individual properties it encompasses:

```
public partial class UserControl1 {

  public UserControl1() {
    InitializeComponent();
    MyProperties = new MyProperties();
  }

  public MyProperties MyProperties { get; set; }
}
```

Create your own [TypeConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayybcxe5.aspx) to handle custom circumstances.

Comment: I tried the code you have inside my UserControl but don't see the properties listed in the designer.

Comment: @Simon Make sure you rebuild the solution.  Which designer are your referring to? The UserControl designer, or the Form with the UserControl selected?

Comment: I hve been rebuilding.  I'm referring to the Form with the UserControl selected.  I have a number of properties which are exposed in the designer already, but this one requires grouping as there are a number of properties related to the same function.

Comment: @Simon Updated example code of my UserControl.  I get a MyProperties item in my PropertyGrid.

Comment: Thanks ever so much for taking time to explain sir. It's all working now!  Instantiating the object was where I went wrong.  (programming 101)  :)